# how to use url and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i wanted to know how do you get

```
http://wesitename.com#overall
```

How to make a div show when the link is #overall ?

Comment: Can you clarify? what "link"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the div has an `id` with the same name, then this should work:

```
$("#"+location.hash).show();
```

`location.hash` will get you the hash-value of a url.

Comment: can i user it like this
    $("#"+location.hash == "#overview").css({"display":"none"})

Comment: That would be

if(location.hash=='#overview') $('#overview').hide();

Answer (score 0):

use `window.location`. On the onLoad event of the page, parse everything after "#" in `window.location.toString()`, and act accordingly.

Comment: Or use location.hash as peirix pointed out. I didn't know about it. It is cross-browser?

Comment: Try it yourself in the browsers you are targeting: http://www.w3schools.com/HTMLDOM/prop_loc_hash.asp

Comment: Yeah, it's been in IE since v.4, FF since v.1 and Opera since v.9...should be safe (: